# Sockets readInt not always working

Tags: java, sockets

i'm building a client-server Java application. The problem is that, when I send Integer with writeInt(), sometimes it blocks on the readInt().

Client

```
PrintWriter socketOut = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
DataOutputStream d = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
String s = "User";
socketOut.println(s);
socketOut.flush();
d.writeInt(data[0]);
d.flush();
d.writeInt(data[1]);
d.flush();
```

Server

```
while(true){
       System.out.println("Listening for clients...");
       clientSock = serverSock.accept();
       Scanner in = new Scanner(clientSock.getInputStream());

       String clientType = in.nextLine();

       switch(clientType){
           case "Resource":
               new Thread(new ResourceService(clientSock)).start();
               break;
           case "User":
               new Thread(new UserService(clientSock)).start();
               break;
       }

    }
```

User Thread

```
@Override
    public void run(){
        try{
        DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(user.getInputStream());
        int i = 0;
        int a = input.readInt(); // Sometimes it blocks here.
        int b = input.readInt();
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
        ...
```

I'm trying to distinguish between clients based on the first string sent to the Server. Sometimes the Server reads the int, and sometimes it blocks.
An example of output is:

```
Listening for clients...
Listening for clients...
Listening for clients...
Listening for clients...
Listening for clients...
1                        // here the server didn't block
100000
Listening for clients...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not a good idea to use DataInputStream/DataOutputStream mixed  together with Scanner and PrintWriter. Scanner and PrintWriter are recommended more for user interaction.

Try to use just DataOutputStream and DataInputStream.

Client

```
DataOutputStream d = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
String s = "User";
d.writeUTF(s);
d.writeInt(data[0]);
d.flush();
d.writeInt(data[1]);
d.flush();
```

Server

```
DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(clientSock.getInputStream());
String clientType = input.readUTF();

switch(clientType){
    case "Resource":
        new Thread(new ResourceService(input)).start();
        break;
    case "User":
        new Thread(new UserService(input)).start();
        break;
```

User thread

```
int a = input.readInt();
int b = input.readInt();
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(b);
```

Note 1: DataInputStream/DataOutputStream use an own protocol to write/read UTF Strings, no need to use a line termination.

Note 2: methods of PrintWriter do not throw I/O Exceptions, you have to check calling `checkError` (probably not the problem here).